# Template Toolkit: evaluating template statements inside a WRAPPER block?

Tags: template-toolkit

Alright, I have looked over the manual for more than two hours now, also tried to find a solution in the badger book, but couldn't come up with anything that works.

The following is the wrapper (`body.tt`), well you get the idea:

```
[%- PROCESS 'const.tt' -%]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
Loads of HTML
[%- content -%]
More HTML
```

The wrapped templates look like this:

```
[% WRAPPER 'body.tt' %]
Other HTML
[%- bar -%]
More other HTML
[% END %]
```

And finally `const.tt` looks like this:

```
[% bar = 'foo' %]
```

... and for some reason the instance of `bar` inside the wrapped template does not get evaluated. Any ideas how I could get that evaluated?

I have tried:

```
[%- content | eval -%]
```

... which did not work.

Note, that in the wrapped template (2nd block above) I want to be able to evaluate the variable `bar` from `const.tt` without having to add another `PROCESS 'const.tt'` to that template. After all the variable should be available from `body.tt`.

And I forgot to mention: Template Toolkit version 2.22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is why what you tried doesn't work.

As http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Directives.html#section_WRAPPER explains, your wrapped content is evaluated first, and then `body.tt` is processed with the already evaluated template passed in as `content`.  Therefore `content` is finished before `content.tt` is loaded.

That said, there is a way to do it, but it is a little ugly.  Here is your content:

```
%- PROCESS 'body.tt' -%]
[%- WRAPPER body -%]
Other HTML
[%- bar -%]
More other HTML
[% END %]
```

Here is `body.tt`:

```
[%- PROCESS 'content.tt' -%]
[% BLOCK body -%]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
Loads of HTML
[%- content -%]
More HTML
[% END -%]
```

And `content.tt` did not change:

```
[% bar = 'foo' %]
```

While this works, I make no promises about the sanity of the person who has to maintain it later.

Comment: first of all thanks for the explanation. +1. Since this proves there is no way to make it work, I'll also award you the bounty and accept.